# Specifying Security Group for EB Load Balancer

Tags: security, https, port, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I spent quite some time finding out that I need to modify the Security Group if I want to enable HTTPS on Elastic Beanstalk. I mean on the frontend, not on the EC2 instance. This is nowhere mentioned in Amazon's documentation. They have this nice switch where you can enable HTTPS and specify the port, but in addition I needed to go to the EC2 console -> Security Groups and find out which Security Group is used by which Load Balancer, and which Load Balancer is used by which EB environment.

Is there a way to specify the Security Group for an Elastic Beanstalk environment? If not, will the load balancer "survive" a rebuilding of the environment or will I need to repeat configuring the ports if the environment is rebuilt?

What's your best practice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To find the name of the security group used in Elastic Load Balancer:

```
AWS console > Network & Security > Load Balancers
```

To change the rules for the Elastic Load Balancer you can either create a new security group and then add it to the Load Balancer, or update an existing security group.

To change the security group for Elastic Beanstalk instances:

```
AWS console > Elastic Beanstalk > Pick environment > Instances > EC2 Security Groups
```

The field contains the names of the security groups (comma separated) that define firewall access to the launched EC2 instances. It will "survive" a rebuilding. If under "rebuilding" you mean code redeployment. If you stop/terminate Elastic Beanstalk environment, the settings will be lost, unless you create a snapshot.

**Update**

There's a way to configure Elastic Load Balancer to "survive" a rebuilding. You need to configure your own Elastic Load Balancer -
[Customizing Environment Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html)

The document has a [code snippet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-environment-resources-elasticache.html) for ElastiCache configuration, you can use it as an example to create Elastic Load Balancer resource.

Also, I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/afternoon/5384101) with Elastic Load Balancer configuration, although I cannot confirm whether it is a working example or not.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, by "rebuilding" I didn't mean code redeployment but what happens when you click in the "Rebuild Environment" button ;) The Elastic Beanstalk UI seems to be a bit half-baked to be honest. You have a field where you can set the EC2 Security Group, but no field where you can set the Security Group of the Load Balancer.

Comment: The real reason for that might be to abstract complexity, with reasonable default settings, if you want to dig deeper, there's always EC2 control panel.

Comment: "Rebuild Environment" deletes and recreates all of the AWS resources (for example: the Auto Scaling group, LoadBalancer, etc.) for a specified environment and forces a restart. So it will drop your ELB balancer and whatever was configured for it.

Comment: @Klemens Updated the answer with details on the ELB customization. Next time I will be more diligent in reading questions.